# Why is require-atomic-updates found here?

Tags: eslint

The [help text for require-atomic-updates](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-atomic-updates)  talks exclusively about statements that both set and consume the same variable.

I have some old† code that looks something like this (I *think* I've included everything that is relevant):

```
var someFunction = async function someFunction () {
  switch(someVariable) {
    case 0:
      if (maybe) {
        await doSomething();
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      //similar to above
  }
  someVariable = 0; // Error detected on this line
  return 
}
var someVariable = 0;
```

someFunction is invoked during some event processing later, while someVariable can be adjusted by multiple code paths

As far as I can tell, the line on which the error is reported *is* an atomic update, it doesn't read the value or set the new value based on anything else.

I can't understand why eslint thinks there is a possible race-condition here?

The code has been functional for a long time now, so I'm happy to just disable the rule on this line to stop it complaining. But I'd like to understand the reason that eslint highlighted it.

† The original code was written long ago, but has been adjusted more recently to be async

Answer (score 2):

If you upgraded to eslint 6.0.1 like I just did, you're encountering a recently introduced bug.

There are several open github issues referencing this bug, but the gist of it is that require-atomic-updates is currently broken.

I recommend downgrading eslint or disabling the rule as a workaround.

Bug reports on the issue here:

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+require-atomic-updates

Comment: Aha, thanks. I'll have to keep an eye out for a fix so I can remove the disabling comment (or comments since it actually came up at least 1 other time)